# Cypress testing element existence

Tags: cypress

I have an error with Cypress, i need to test for the presence of an element, i use cy.find(selector).length" but this command returns an error.

```
if (cy.find('.mdl-textfield__error').length > 0 || cy.find('.mdl-selectfield__error').length > 0) {

        }
```

Do you have an idea of the origin of the problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add the error that you are getting in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of incorrect usage.
As documentation says: `.find() requires being chained off a command that yields DOM element(s).` Please go through [cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#Syntax) and [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/find/) documentations for more detailed explanations.

Related to your code example, you have to locate the parent element(which usually is always rendered), then search for its descendants:

```
cy.get('.parentSelector').then($parent => {
    if ($parent.find('.mdl-textfield__error ').length > 0) {

    // your code

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exact usage would be a bit weird to actually use in Cypress. The closest equivalent would be a Cypress chain like...

```js
/**
* Both `.should('exist')`s are implied by the `.get()`, but explicitly
* stating what you are doing is good.
*/
cy.get('.mdl-textfield__error').should('exist')
  .get('.mdl-selectfield__error').should('exist')
  // rest of your code
```

The above will work even if there are multiple elements matching those selectors. Additionally, the test will fail if either of those selectors *does not* yield any elements. That may not be your intended use, [but Cypress does endorse conditional testing except under specific uses.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#The-situations) (If you *know* you'll have these errors present, then just test that they are present!)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the basic syntax errors as mentioned, if you look at the DOM you'll see that the error elements are ***always*** present, so testing for `length > 0` or `.should('exist')` does nothing useful.

If you want to check if errors occurred test the inner text(s)

```js
cy.get('.mdl-textfield__error').invoke('text').then(textfieldError => {
  cy.get('.mdl-selectfield__error').invoke('text').then(selectfieldError => {

    if (textfieldError || selectfieldError) {
      ... an error has occurred in one of the fields
    }
  })
})
```

You can also check for the `is-invalid` class which is used to control the error message and the red color

```js
cy.get('.mdl-textfield').then($textfield => {
  cy.get('.mdl-selectfield').then($selectfield => {

    if ($textfield.hasClass(is-invalid) || $selectfield.hasClass(is-invalid)) {
      ... an error has occurred in one of the fields
    }
  })
})
```